# Restrict Deletion of Customers/Products to Specific Users Based on Roles?

Tags: magento-1.8, admin

Is there a way to easily through an extension or some magical code that my developer can implement for us to restrict or at least provide a confirmation pop up before deleting a customer or a product from the database?

Barring that is there a way for us to restrict the delete button from appearing from certain users through admin defined roles?

Answer (score 1):

Yes,***This can be possible by doing some customization at system.***

Using `controller_action_predispatch` event you can do this.
and this event check admin user loggedin.

Then get admin user from session   `$session = Mage::getSingleton('admin/session');` and

`$user = $session->getUser();` and at this observer check current action and controller name.

And if find the fullAction martch weith delete action then redirect to last page